# Why my data get undefined when I successfully get the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, supabase

I don't know why I get `undefined` when I tried to `console.log` at my final step in `UseEffect`

I've successfully gotten the response, the response returns to me with 200 status and data in it.

[image]

I designed my database like this

2 tables,
`animes` table contains unique `anime_title` and auto-increment `id`.

```
id  anime_title anime_image anime_url
```

`anime_detail` table contains a foreign key that is linked with `anime-title` in `animes` table

```
id anime_title anime_episode anime_url
```

So in my code, I tried to get `anime_title` in my `animes` table in superbase based on the `id` from the `useParams`

I've successfully gotten both of them, and successfully use the `anime_title` to get all the `anime_episode` based on the `anime_title`

But when I tried to `console.log` the last step, it return to me `undefined` value, which I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import './animedetail.css'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { supabase } from '../../supabaseClient'

function AnimeDetail(){

    let animeID = useParams()

    useEffect(async () => {
        // GET ID
        let id = await animeID.id
        console.log(id)

        // QUERY WITH ID
        const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from('animes')
        .select('id, anime_title, anime_url')
        .match({id: id})

        // GET ANIME TITLE BY ID
        let animeTitle = await data[0].anime_title
        console.log(animeTitle)

        // GET EPISODE BASED ON ANIME TITLE
        const {dataInfo} = await supabase
        .from(`anime_detail`)
        .select(`id, anime_title, anime_url, anime_episode`)
        .filter(`anime_title`, `in`, `(${animeTitle})`)

        console.log(dataInfo)
    }, [animeID])


    return (
        <>
        <div className = "anime-list-section">
        <h2>Anime Detail:</h2>
        <p></p>
        </div>
        </>
    )

}
export default AnimeDetail
```

Comment: `let animeTitle = await data[0].anime_title` not sure how referencing a property would need await.

Comment: It seems off to me that in the first supabase query you destruct the result into `{data, error}` while the second usage deconstructs to `{dataInfo}` are you sure that is right?

Comment: @epascarello Totally agreed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove that `await`, it's a panic move I guess, I just tried to workaround to see if it's worked or not.

Comment: @Tobi can you explains more to me, I seem totally lost, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation of supabase-js (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/filter) there is no `dataInfo` in the result of a filter query. Instead its just what you have above that when you executed the first query.

Deconstruct the result like the following to gather your information

```js
// GET EPISODE BASED ON ANIME TITLE
const const {data: dataInfo, error: errorInfo } = await supabase // no dataInfo, but data, error like in the documentation
    .from(`anime_detail`)
    .select(`id, anime_title, anime_url, anime_episode`)
    .filter(`anime_title`, `in`, `(${animeTitle})`)

console.log(dataInfo)
```

Comment: that will be an error. You now have data declared twice

Comment: But I've used the `data` above, it won't let me declare again.

Comment: Sure thing, did not think about the redeclaration

Comment: It can be done with `const {data: dataInfo, error: errorInfo } = ....; console.log(dataInfo);`

Comment: @Tobi thanks, the `res` declare worked for me, I haven't thought of it based on the document I read on supabase. Many thanks.

Comment: Just using the `res` const will retrieve the full object. The approach of deconstructing the objects fields to only the ones you need is better practice. Thats why its documented like that in the supabase docs. I updated my answer as proposed by @epascarello